# How to find non ascii characters from cmd in windows?

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a big file which contains some non ascii chars. I need to find out those records. Note: I am not able to open the file using Notepad++ etc.

I tried something like this from cmd : >**findstr /R /N "[^\x00-\x7F]" Test.txt**

But this is returning extra rows which doesn't contain non ascii chars

Example of the chars: �

```
Test.txt contains:

 �      
asdf
sdf asd
1231 sdfg dfg

Result:
1: ∩┐╜  ►←→    ☼    --Expected row
3:sdf asd           --Unexpected row
4:1231 sdfg dfg     --Unexpected row
```

Comment: What do you mean by "record", a line? Also, what's the character encoding used by the text file? If you use the right encoding, the characters might not actually be �  .

Comment: Yes, I mean line, What I want is that I want to find out lines and remove from the file. The encoding is UTF-8 w/o BOM. Also I don't create these files. It will be sent by another resource. They won't change encoding.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. UTF-8 files contain two-byte characters, so you cannot simply scan for bytes greater than `\x7F`. Even if it would work using `findstr /V /R /C:"[\x80+\xFF]` (you'd need to specify the characters literally as `findstr` does not understand excaped hex. codes), I am quite shure that it would not work due to [`findstr` bugs and limitations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868)...

Comment: Install gVim and use your regex there.

Comment: @aschipfl - True that FINDSTR cannot. But by definition, any byte between 0x80-0xFF is non-ASCII. UTF-8 cannot encode a non-ASCII character without such a byte. So a line contains a non-ASCII character if and only if it contains at least one byte between 0x80-0xFF.

Comment: You could use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - `jrepl "[^\x00-\x7F]" "" /k 0 /f yourfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set "F=1.txt" & echo var r=0,c=0,l,s=(new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")).OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0),1);while(!s.AtEndOfStream){++c;if(/[^^\r\n\x20-\x7f]/.test(l=s.ReadLine())){r=1;WScript.Echo(c+": "+l);}}s.Close();WScript.Quit(r);>"%TEMP%\1.js" & (call cscript /nologo "%TEMP%\1.js" "%F%") & del "%TEMP%\1.js" & set "F="
```

`set "F=1.txt"` is a file to test.

`echo ... >"%TEMP%\1.js"` creates a JScript file that will read `%F%` and test if it contains `/[^\r\n\x20-\x7f]/` symbols.

`cscript` launches the created script.

`del "%TEMP%\1.js" & set "F="` is a cleanup.